# Software to edit TIFF files

Tags: windows-7, images, gui, tiff

We're looking for a relatively simple program for Win 7 to open and edit multi-page TIFF files. It doesn't need Photoshop's level of features. Just being able to delete a page from the TIFF is sufficient. We're not looking for a command-line tool; we need a GUI for folks who are not computer experts.

Any tools you can recommend (free or paid)? Thanks.

Comment: Not a duplicate. Not looking for a command line tool. Need a GUI program to open and edit TIFF files.

Comment: when you said that deleting a page was sufficient, I undestood that spliting the pages, deleting one, and joining the others was enought...

Comment: Read this post, [you must](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software/5373#5373)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from IrfanView (see above) you can give the Paint.NET a chance (download for example here): http://download.cnet.com/Paint-NET/3000-2192_4-10338146.html

> If all you want is a quick image retouch, Photoshop is overkill.
>   Paint.NET, on the other hand, is an open-source freeware editor with
>   all the essentials, including tools to crop, rotate, and resize
>   images, adjust colors, and create collages. It supports common image
>   formats--JPEG, PNG, GIF, **TIFF**, and others--but not high-resolution RAW
>   files.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Paint.NET as it doesn't support multi-line TIFF documents

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure how this ended up being marked as the answer. It doesn't seem like Paint.NET supports multi-page TIFF at all.

Answer (score 4):

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) is great for simple editing tasks (resizing, cropping,...) and handles TIFF files.
It is also free of charge (but not free software)